# How to create edges based on the equality check on vertex attributes in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, redisgraph

How to create edges based on the equality check on vertex attributes in Cypher?

For example: lets say I have one object like this

`Employees {name: "abc, country: "NZ"}`

and lets say I have the following objects

`Manager { name: "abc", depatment: "product"}`

`Manager {name: "abc", depatment: "sales"}`

`Manager {name: "abc", depatment: "marketing"}`

Now I want to create all the edges where `Employees.name = Manager.name`

How do I write the Cypher query to create all 4 vertices and 3 edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the pairs first with `MATCH` clause and then `CREATE` a relationship between them.

```
MATCH (e:Employees),(m:Manager)
WHERE e.name=m.name
WITH e,m
CREATE (m)-[:REL_NAME]->(e)
```

Comment: Thanks. Another related question from this what if I have country list so say Country{name: NZ} and i want to create all the edges where e.name =m.name and e.county = country.name? Can MATCH take more than two vertices ?

Comment: Yes, It can take more than two vertices